# Adding xml element to a list from XML reader

Tags: c#, .net, xml, list, xmlreader

I have an xml file called portfolio that I am passing the location of as a string.
Read a list of filenames from the portfolio file, under the  element. In the xml file I have an element called  that I need to read the 4 values in the price data and store it to a List of strings. I don't know if I am doing this correctly. I don't know what my parameters should be for the foreach loop.

XML file:

```
<priceData>
    <file name="ibmx.xml"/>
    <file name="msft.xml"/>
    <file name="ulti.xml"/>
    <file name="goog.xml"/>
</priceData>
```

Here is my function for C#

```
public static  void readPortfolio(string filename)
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
    reader.Read();
    List<string> priceDataFile = new List <string> ();
    foreach(var file in reader) //Don't know what the parameters should be.
    {
        priceDataFile.Add(reader.Value); //Not sure if I am passing what I want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this . the following will add the filename of each attribute to the list
replace where I have declared a copy of your `.XML` file with your path location.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Sample_Xml\PriceData.xml");
List<string> priceDataFile = new List<string>();
var priceData = (from pd in document.Descendants("priceData")
                  select pd);

foreach (XElement priceValue in priceData.Elements())
{
    priceDataFile.Add(priceValue.FirstAttribute.Value.ToString());
}
```

this is what your priseDataFile List Contents will look like 
viewing it in the QuickWatch

```
[0] "ibmx.xml"
[1] "msft.xml"
[2] "ulti.xml"
[3] "goog.xml"
```

Comment: You don't need `ToList()` here.

Comment: I edited the answer and tested it it works thanks abatishchev

Answer (score 0):

Using XDocument Class is a good way to solve it.But if you want to use XmlTextReader Class, the code has been listed as follow. Then you will get the result which contains a XML file list. On the onther way, name is an attribute in your example code. So you should use reader.GetAttribute("name") to get value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlReaderTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("../../Portfolio.xml");
            reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
            List<string> priceDataFile = new List<string>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "file")
                {
                    priceDataFile.Add(reader.GetAttribute("name"));
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }

            reader.Close();

            foreach (string file in priceDataFile)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I agree with you. If Martin is not necessary to use XmlTextReader Class, XDocument Class is better. Linq will simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to XML instead (.NET 3.0+):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
List<string> list = doc.Root
                       .Elements("file")
                       .Select(f => (string)f.Atribute("name"))
                       .ToList();
```